# outlook command-line switches

Tags: command-line-interface, outlook

I'm trying to produce a shortcut for user that will launch their outlook email or calendar.
the switches I'm using are:

- /select outlook:inbox   (or /select outlook:calendar)
- /recycle (so that there is only one outlook window open)

They both work independently, but when I try and use them together I get *"The command line argument is not valid. Verify the switch you are using."*

The full shortcut is

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 2007\Office12\OUTLOOK.EXE"  /select "outlook:calendar" /recycle
```

Answer (score 1):

This was a [known problem](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823923) with Outlook 2003. Have you tried using the same workaround with Oulook 2007? In your case this would be:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 2007\Office12\OUTLOOK.EXE" /recycle outlook:calendar
```

Comment: this has exactly the same problem. Note this: http://blogs.msdn.com/rgregg/archive/2007/12/03/command-line-parameter-changes-in-outlook.aspx

Answer (score 0):

According to this [page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HP010031101033.aspx), the /recycle switch can be used with the /explorer and /folder switches.  I believe that running without a switch is like using the /explorer switch.  It must simply not be compatible with any other switches.